# java reflections list NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, list, arraylist, reflection, nosuchmethoderror

I'm currently working on a commandline-client for automated testing. For this, I want to be able to perform a request just by a given name, so I have to use reflection.

However, I get the following error:

> NoSuchMethodException: java.util.ArrayList.add(some.path.Foo)

on this code:

```
Object job = Class.forName(sClassName).getConstructor().newInstance();

List<?> jobObject = (List<?>) Request.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(sMethodName).invoke(Request);
jobObject.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("add", job.getClass()).invoke(Request, job);
```

On the other hand, the following code works (but is not the solution as Foo should be dynamic, not hardcoded)

```
Object job = Class.forName(sClassName).getConstructor().newInstance();

List<Foo> jobObject = (List<Foo>) Request.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(sMethodName)).invoke(Request);
jobObject.add((Foo)job);
```

Sidenote:

- sClassName = **some.path.Foo**
- *.getDeclaredMethod(sMethod).invoke(Request)* returns an Object (which is a **List< Foo>**)

What I want to achieve is to get the code working with dynamic inputs (for example **Bar** instead of **Foo**)

Comment: In your code, what is `Request` ?

Comment: Request is a class which provides the service request I want to test. This request requires a job which can be set like above, as Request contains a List with job-objects (in this case "Foo").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to [**type erasure**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), the method `add` of a `List` expects at runtime an object of type `Object` (in other words its signature is `boolean add(Object o)`) moreover you need to invoke it on `jobObject` not on `Request` as it is not a `List`, so your code should rather be:

```
 jobObject.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("add", Object.class).invoke(jobObject, job);
```

---

Unless I miss something for me you don't even need reflection in this case

```
List<Object> jobObject = (List<Object>)...
jobObject.add(job);
```

Comment: Beat me by seconds.

Comment: with this code I get an "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class"

Comment: have you changed `Request` to `jobObject`?